# Reordering Indices for matrix multiplication in c++

Tags: c++

```
const int n=50;
    double a[n][n];
    double b[n][n];
    double c[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            cout << c[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
```

I currently have a working code that multiplies two nxn matrices. I am trying to reorder the indices (ie i,k,j ... k,i,j) without touching the equation that does the multiplication. I am doing this to see how the order of the indices affects performance time, but if I just change the 'j's to 'k's and vice versa in my loops, my multiplication equation will not be correct. 
I am wondering if what I am attempting to do is possible and if anyone can shed some light on what steps I can take to achieve this.

Comment: Shouldn't reordering the `for (int i/j/k = 0;...` lines do what you are trying to do? :-) But you should print out the matrix at the end of multiplication, not during, for this to work.

Comment: What do you mean at the end? Outside the for loops? If I do this, won't I not have access to the i,j,k variables?

Comment: He means use a second set of for loops to print out the c array. I also think that re-ordering the for statements should be OK.

Comment: You won't, but you can write another two for loops to loop through the "matrix" and print it out. Also, if you are timing execution time of algorithm, you really shouldn't be writing to stdout in the execution path.

Comment: That worked out great. I'm not sure why I couldn't think of that solution myself. As for the execution time, I am starting the clock, running all of the loops and such that print my matrix multiplication, then ending the clock. I am then printing out the difference between the two. Is this not optimal? I am not sure what exactly you mean by "writing to stdout in the execution path". EDIT:  my question was answered below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be printing out the c matrix at the point you are doing so, especially if you are trying to time an algorithm. What you should be doing is more similar to this:

```
const int n=50;
double a[n][n];
double b[n][n];
double c[n][n];

/* First multiply the matrices a,b into c. */
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }
}

/* now print out the result for visual correctness check */
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        std::cout << c[i][j] << ' '; //this will leave a space after last character, but for this use case, nobody cares.
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can just switch around the lines containing for loops (ie. `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`) around, and see if changing access pattern changes execution time/results.

*Spoiler: It shouldn't affect results except in some border cases of weird values inside the matrices, that are caused by inexactness of floating point math. It should however affect execution time, but it will be brutally dominated by time taken by printing the matrix, unless measured properly.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about performance time then It always come down to complexity. No matter how you change the order, your complexity is defined by the area of code which is doing most of your work.

Here all your loops run till `n`. Now no matter what order you change you have complexity of order O(n^3) Unless you change your logic. The best Matrix Multiplication Algorithm known so far is the [Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) with O(n^2.3736 ) complexity but it is not used for practical purposes.

But you can use [Strassen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) which has O(n^2.8074 ) complexity

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is one thing, real world performance is another. If you don't believe me, look up how matrix multiplication is actually implemented and how much pain is taken to maximize cache-friendliness of the access pattern.

Comment: Come on. Performance directly depends on complexity. If not why do we have different sorting algos? Go compare performance time of each sorting algo.

Comment: Oh, while it certainly does, there are some other important factors to it. (See how any good Quicksort implementation actually ends up using Insertionsort at some point or try summing up a large (large enough so it doesn't find into L1 and L2 cache) array of values, once sequentially and once by accessing random indices. (Okay, that would be non-trivial to perform fairly, as summing via random indices would have more overhead anyway in getting the random indices))